# Magento 2:How to show Gift Card History in Account Page?

Tags: magento2, gift-card

In Magento 2 Commerce, we cannot see the customer's gift card history in Account page. We can only redeem and see the status of gift card by putting the gift card code.

How can I show the gift card history against customers?

Please guide

Comment: Out the box i don't think there is a functionality for this maybe something you may need to create.

Comment: @Dava Gordon, Yes, its not available by default. Can you please give some idea to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You would need to get all current users order data and get all previously used giftcards from those orders. it should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Yes @DavaGordon

Comment: @DavaGordon Can you please point me out for any guidance on that?

Comment: First of all you will need to create a custom module, then write a block which gets the current users order data. with magento 2 now you will need to do this by private content as magneto is getting more secure when it comes to customer data. once you have that information it should just be a matter of filtering through orders if a coupon was used if so simply store that data into an array and then use the gift card collection to map the data to get the values you want.